# In Openedge ABL (Progress 4GL) how create a new row when defining a browse?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I have looked all over the web for this information and I'm tempted to assume that's it not possible at this point. To be clear, I have:

1. defined a temp-table(x) and 4 fields
2. defined a query(q) for the temp-table(x)
3. defined a browse(b) for the query(q)
4. defined a frame(f) for the browse(b)
5. filtered my data, created temp-table(xx), and assigned the filtered data to the temp-table(x)
6. Opened a query(q) for each temp-table(x)

What I'm unable to do within the define browse(b) query(q) display statement is use skip to place one of the fields from temp-table(xx) on a different row. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ABL does not support a multi-line browse. Depending on your OpenEdge release, you should use an Active X or .NET Control.